# Delete related records-Realm

Tags: android, realm

I have recently started working with Realm on Android and still trying to understand it. I have a following class-

```
Class A extends RealmObject{
double count;
}

Class B extends RealmObject{
RealList<A> ListofA;
}
```

I want to select all instances of A with count>0 . So I construct this query-

```
List<A> wantedAList=return realm.where(A.class)
.greaterThan("count",0)
.findAll();
```

Now I want to delete all the records of A (related to any B) from realm which are not part of wantedAList. So I do this-

```
//find all the records of A
List<A> allA=realm.where(A).findAll();
//using Google Guava to find difference of sets
Set<A> allASet= Sets.newHashSet(allA);
Set<A> wantedASet= Sets.newHashSet(wantedAList);
Set<A> unWantedlASet=Sets.difference(allASet,walntedaset);
RealmList<A> newAList=new RealmList<A>();
        A.addAll(Lists.newArrayList(unWantedlEvalUnitsSet));
        A.deleteAllFromRealm();
```

Please let me know if I am doing the right thing here. I have simplified the problem here. In actual code the wantedAList is composed from complex where clauses and hence this approach.

I also want to check if deleting newAList from realm will automatically update B instances with refreshed list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) You will have problem by adding `RealmObject` to a `HashSet`. See https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realmobjects-hashcode

2) Use [`RealmQuery.not()`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#not--) To create the unwanted list and delete it

```
RealmResults<A> unwantedList = realm.where(A.class)
    .not()
    .greaterThan("count",0)
    .findAll();
unwantedList.deleteAllFromRealm();
```

3 After `RealmObject` of type `A` gets deleted from Realm, the corresponding object in `B.ListOfA` will be automatically removed as well.